# How to convert few columns of pandas dataframe into JSON record within another record?

Tags: json, python-2.7, pandas

So I am trying to convert a pandas Dataframe with 12+ columns into corresponding JSON Record. I'm able to get it. However, I want few columns of the frame to be a subrecord of a new column. How this can be achieved.?

```
{
                    "ADRNR": 2692629, 
                    "AlertID": "", 
                    "AlertTimestamp": "14-12-2015 14:44:14", 
                    "BANKL": null, 
                    "BANKN": null, 
                    "BANKS": "nan", 
                    "BEGRU": "NPIV", 
                    "BUKRS": "2646", 
                    "C_Block": "No", 
                    "KOINH": null, 
                    "LAND1": "US", 
                    "LOEVM_x": null, 
                    "LOEVM_y": null, 
                    "MasterDataID": "10099", 
                    "MasterDataType": "Vendor", 
                    "NAME1": "LEGAL", 
                    "NODEL_x": null, 
                    "NODEL_y": null, 
                    "ORT01": null, 
                    "OtherData": null, 
                    "PSTLZ": null, 
                    "RuleID": "Rule3", 
                    "RuleName": "Vendor and Bank Country is Different", 
                    "STCD1": null, 
                    "STCD2": null, 
                    "STCEG": null, 
                    "STRAS": null, 
                    "TELF1": null
               }
```

The above JSON is what I Get. But I want the following structure. Kindly guide me.

```
 {

                "RuleID": "Rule3", 
                "RuleName": "Vendor and Bank Country is Different", 
                "AlertID": "", 
                "AlertTimestamp": "14-12-2015 14:44:14", 
                "MasterDataID": "10099", 
                "MasterDataType": "Vendor", 
                "OtherData": {
                    "BANKL": null, 
                    "BANKN": null, 
                    "BANKS": "nan", 
                    "BEGRU": "NPIV", 
                    "BUKRS": "2646", 
                    "C_Block": "No", 
                    "KOINH": null, 
                    "LAND1": "US", 
                    "LOEVM_x": null, 
                    "LOEVM_y": null, 
                    "NAME1": "LEGAL", 
                    "NODEL_x": null, 
                    "NODEL_y": null, 
                    "ORT01": null,
                    "PSTLZ": null, 
                    "ADRNR": 2692629,
                    "STCD1": null, 
                    "STCD2": null, 
                    "STCEG": null, 
                    "STRAS": null, 
                    "TELF1": null
                }
           }
```

Edit : Flg is my code

```
Final_Table['AlertID'] = ''
Final_Table['AlertTimestamp'] = datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
Final_Table['MasterDataType'] = 'Vendor'
Final_Table['RuleID'] = 'Rule3'
Final_Table['RuleName'] = 'Vendor and Bank Country is Different'
Final_Table = Final_Table.rename(columns={'LIFNR': 'MasterDataID'})


Result = Final_Table[Final_Table['BANKS'] != Final_Table['LAND1']]

Result['OtherData'] = np.NaN


final_result = {'alerts': json.loads(Result.to_json(orient = 'records',force_ascii = False).encode('utf8'))}
result = {'results': final_result}

with open('output_Rule3.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(result, outfile, indent = 5, sort_keys = True)
log.info("Rule3 : Execution Successful")
```

Comment: Can you show your efforts

Comment: @EdChum Added the code !

Comment: What's the difference between what you want and what you're getting?  They look pretty similar.

Comment: @JohnZwinck  I want few columns to go into "OtherData".  You would notice the difference if u compare OtherData in both JSON's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than within `pandas`, I would modify the `json` output.

Starting with your `json` data

```
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

[
    {
        "ADRNR": 2692629,
        "AlertID": "",
        "AlertTimestamp": "14-12-2015 14:44:14",
        "BANKL": null,
        "BANKN": null,
        "BANKS": "nan",
        "BEGRU": "NPIV",
        "BUKRS": "2646",
        "C_Block": "No",
        "KOINH": null,
        "LAND1": "US",
        "LOEVM_x": null,
        "LOEVM_y": null,
        "MasterDataID": "10099",
        "MasterDataType": "Vendor",
        "NAME1": "LEGAL",
        "NODEL_x": null,
        "NODEL_y": null,
        "ORT01": null,
        "OtherData": null,
        "PSTLZ": null,
        "RuleID": "Rule3",
        "RuleName": "Vendor and Bank Country is Different",
        "STCD1": null,
        "STCD2": null,
        "STCEG": null,
        "STRAS": null,
        "TELF1": null
    }
]
```

and a list of some of the `columns` you are interested in:

```
other_data = ["BANKL", "BANKN", "BANKS", "BEGRU", "BUKRS", "C_Block"]
```

you can modify the `json` directly:

```
for i, record in enumerate(data):
    data[i]['OtherData'] = {}
    for key in list(record.keys()):
        if key in other_data:
            data[i]['OtherData'][key] = record[key]
            del data[i][key]

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

[
    {
        "ADRNR": 2692629,
        "AlertID": "",
        "AlertTimestamp": "14-12-2015 14:44:14",
        "KOINH": null,
        "LAND1": "US",
        "LOEVM_x": null,
        "LOEVM_y": null,
        "MasterDataID": "10099",
        "MasterDataType": "Vendor",
        "NAME1": "LEGAL",
        "NODEL_x": null,
        "NODEL_y": null,
        "ORT01": null,
        "OtherData": {
            "BANKL": null,
            "BANKN": null,
            "BANKS": "nan",
            "BEGRU": "NPIV",
            "BUKRS": "2646",
            "C_Block": "No"
        },
        "PSTLZ": null,
        "RuleID": "Rule3",
        "RuleName": "Vendor and Bank Country is Different",
        "STCD1": null,
        "STCD2": null,
        "STCEG": null,
        "STRAS": null,
        "TELF1": null
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It did work. I was struggling to format it right before it is converted to JSON.